# What kind of join, if any, is appropriate here?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to (my)SQL and I need to know how (or if it's even possible) to build a particular query.

I have 3 tables, simplified below:

```
Actions
-------
actionID | staffID | actionDetails | actionDate


Staff
-----
staffID | departmentID | userName | firstName | lastName


Departments
-----------
departmentID | departmentName
```

As you can see, departmentID is a FK in the Staff table, and staffID is a FK in the Actions table.

I want to pull the following fields based on departmentID:

- userName
- firstName
- lastName
- actionDetails
- actionDate

Can this be done in a single query with joins or do I need to pull staffIDs and then iterate through them?

Again, I'm new at this and it's kinda wrecking my brain at the moment. I don't think I'm cut out for this!

Comment: "Can this be done in a single query with joins" Yes: look at this most excellent article to help explain joins: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html  We all start somewhere.  Think of tables/joins in terms of "sets" of data.  and that you're just combining different sets to get data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Query.

```
select 
S.userName,
S.firstName,
S.lastName,
A.actionDetails,
A.actionDate
from Departments D 
join Staff S on d.departmentID=s.departmentID
join Actions A on s.staffID=A.staffID
WHERE D.departmentID = YourDeparmentID;
```

**Types Of JOIN in SQl**
[image: Types of Join in SQL]

Comment: instead of image a link would be suffecient!

Comment: I dislike this image. Thinking of joins as operation on sets complicate thing a lot! This doesn't explain relations between tables, which is much more essential.

Comment: Actually, I think the image enhances the answer.

Comment: These images (and the visual "explanations" of Joins) should die in fire. They are nice explanations, but of set operations (Unions, Interesects, Differences). They do not explain joins, only a very limited kind of joins.

Comment: Thanks! That query was exactly what I needed. Obviously, I have a lot more reading to do. The image might be helpful after I do some more reading, but I'm marking as accepted because the query was perfect (and helps me understand this particular type of join more than the image does, to be honest).

Comment: @stoo I am glad that my Answer helped you. But it was very basic. You need a lot of learning, try studying basics from **[W3SCHOOLS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)**

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, this can be done with joins. In fact, that's what joins are designed for. When you're writing SQL, you don't want to think in terms of iterating through IDs; instead, think of getting the data all at once, in "sets." You can use your foreign keys to expand those sets, essentially creating one large set that encompasses multiple tables.

```
SELECT Staff.userName, Staff.firstName, Staff.lastName, 
  Actions.actionDetails, Actions.actionDate
FROM Staff
INNER JOIN Departments ON Departments.DepartmentID = Staff.DepartmentID
INNER JOIN Actions ON Actions.StaffID = Staff.StaffID
```

You'll notice that in other answers, folks have used *aliases* such as `Staff as s` to simplify their statements. This is pretty common, and makes things more readable; I've left those out here to make the join syntax a little clearer.

The example I've provided uses *inner joins* -- it will return only records where a match can be made between `Staff`, `Departments`, and `Actions`. If you want to return all rows for one or more tables, and return `null` for the other tables when a match can't be found, you can use *outer joins*.

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to give a simple answer because this is probably just the beginning of many types of issues like this you will have. So I'd rather tell you how I think about it, and maybe that will help  you to do the other ones as well.

As mentioned in comments and other answers above, think of these as sets. Think of how they relate to each other. Then think about what columns you want to get back, and think about how you determine which rows you want to see.

So, to start with, I write a FROM clause to handle where the records come from (and I give them shorter names, or aliases, to make it easier to follow):

```
FROM Departments d
  INNER JOIN Staff s
  INNER JOIN Actions a
```

Now, how are they related? In this case, they relate exactly like the PK -> FK relationships as you mentioned. So I add that to the FROM clause:

```
FROM Departments d
  INNER JOIN Staff s 
    ON s.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId
  INNER JOIN Actions a
    ON a.StaffId = s.StaffId
```

Now I decide what columns I want to get back, using the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT userName, firstName, lastName, actionDetails, actionDate
```

But which table do I get those columns from? I add the table aliases in:

```
SELECT s.userName, s.firstName, s.lastName, a.actionDetails, a.actionDate
```

(Note that in this case, there are no columns appearing in more than one table, so aliases are not absolutely necessary, though they are a very good practice.)

Finally, I add the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE d.DepartmentId = 20
```

or whatever department id you seek.

The final answer then is something like this:

```
SELECT s.userName, s.firstName, s.lastName, a.actionDetails, a.actionDate
FROM Departments d
  INNER JOIN Staff s 
    ON s.DepartmentId = d.DepartmentId
  INNER JOIN Actions a
    ON a.StaffId = s.StaffId
WHERE d.DepartmentId = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

For department id 1

```
SELECT
    s.userName,
    s.firstName,
    s.lastName,
    a.actionDetails,
    a.actionDate
FROM Staff AS s
LEFT JOIN Departments AS d ON d.departmentID = s.departmentID
LEFT JOIN Actions AS a ON a.staffID = s.staffID
WHERE d.departmentID = 1;
```